# Attiny85 Burn Bootloader Error [Device signature = 0x000000] [SOLVED]

Tags: arduino, attiny, bootloader, error, attiny85

I had read in different forums about similar issues and double-check the connections and datasheet. But it's still not working for me. First of all, I will share my build and my configuration. Later the error.

#### *The Connections*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMtH9c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

#### *The Configuration*

I know that it's in Spanish, I apologize for that but it can also be read.

[image]

#### *The Previous Steps*

I ran without the capacitor the "ArduinoISP" example code added with the plugin: "ATTinyCore" (also I tried to reinstall it but no changes). Later when I load the settings mentioned in the Configuration part and click "Burn Bootloader" it fails...

#### *The Error*

[image]

I have no clue why this is happening. Maybe a clue could be that before burning the bootloader with these specs I miss-clicked and ran the burn bootloader with this plate:

[image]

I don't know if I broke the ATtiny85 doing that. The error:

> **avrdude**: Yikes! Invalid device signature. Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override this check.

> Error burning bootloader

#### *My Research*

Meanwhile, I asked in Discord's servers with no answer I surfed on forums and I found a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T37w6zyLnY0&ab_channel=RoelVandePaar) with the same console name error. And suggest connecting Attiny85 Pin Nº1 to GND before the burning:

[image]

#### *The Question*

What I'm doing wrong? Is my Attiny85 dead?

#### *Update*

I will put the output verbose complete error:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\santa\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM3
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
         AVR Part                      : ATtiny85
         Chip Erase delay              : 400000 us
         PAGEL                         : P00
         BS2                           : P00
         RESET disposition             : possible i/o
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    12     4    0 no        512    4      0  4000  4500 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6    32    0 yes      8192   64    128 30000 30000 0xff 0xff
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.03s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

An error occurred while uploading the sketch
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.03s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I will hightlight some stuff that could give a clue:

`avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000`

Also, I saw:

`Vtarget         : 0.0 V`

So in theory no voltage in the Attiny?

#### Error Solved!

Thanks all for helping with dm and collaborating. It was just a dumb error haha. In fact with Arduino Mega the attiny setup are different. Because intead of using

`10->reset| 11->mosi | 12->miso | 13->Sck`

they changed to:

`10->reset| 51->mosi | 50->miso | 52->Sck`

I made a fast draw in ASCII for how to plug in the Attiny85 using an Arduino Mega 2560:

[image: mistake: referential**]
----Mistake: referential**-----

[image]

Comment: please add a question that you would like answered to your post

Comment: Post updated: 
-New information more accurate (Log output)
-Punctual questions more specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solved]
As I added in the thread, I could solve the problem. Thanks so much for helping.

## Solution:

In Arduino Mega the ATTiny setup uses different pins. Because intead of using:

```
10->reset| 11->mosi | 12->miso | 13->Sck
```

it uses:

```
10->reset| 51->mosi | 50->miso | 52->Sck
```

[More info here](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/arduino-isp/ArduinoISP), I highly recommend visiting this website before buying components.

I made a simple draft in ASCII for being more intuitive:

[image]
----Mistake: referential**-----

Answer (score 0):

If you've programmed ATTinyCore with Micronucleus bootloader, it disables RESET via fuses and you no longer can use ISP to program it. From [this description](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore/blob/master/avr/extras/UsingMicronucleus.md), part "Disabling reset":

> **Disabling Reset**

> Because a board running the Micronucleus bootloader
> can be reprogrammed without the use of the RESET pin, it is practical
> to use them with reset configured to act as an I/O pin. This is,
> obviously, of particular utility on the ATtiny85, where available pins
> are at a premium, but may be used on any part (except the ATtiny841,
> in the current version of this core). Because this requires changing
> the fuses, it can only be enabled with an ISP programmer. Once reset
> as been disabled, it can no longer be programmed via ISP. Only HVSP or
> parallel programming (depending on the part - each part supports one
> or the other, never both), wherein 12v is applied to the reset pin
> under specific conditions, can be used to unset this fuse or to
> unbrick a part where reset is disabled and the bootloader is no longer
> functioning. Note that the bootloader can still be upgraded over USB -
> including to a version that only runs upon external reset!

It is designed to use with USB bootloader called micronucleus once burnt. You can assemble a variant of Digispark board and use it via USB now:

[image: Digispart board schematic]

Or you can assemble a tool called [Fusebit Doctor](https://www.radiolocman.com/shem/schematics.html?di=65084). Which can reset fuses to default via HVPP/HVSP programming methods.

Ignore VTarget message, ArduinoISP simply doesn't supports reading target voltage so it always shows 0V.

Comment: Thanks so much for the information! I'll keep it just in case :D. Luckily in this case it's not an issue with the reset fuse it's just wrong pin connection